# Fortran array inside an array

Tags: arrays, matrix, fortran, cell, fortran90

I want to obtain an array but this array include more array its inside. I will describe in an example! I want to create 4 matrix. Main matrix is E.

```
   Program array1
   !*************************************************! 
   implicit none

   INTEGER, PARAMETER :: m=2 !rows
   INTEGER, PARAMETER :: n=2 !cols
   Real, DIMENSION(m,n) :: A,D
   Real, DIMENSION(1,2) :: B,C

   REAL, allocatable,DIMENSION(:,:) :: E
   allocate(E(4,4))
   ! Assign values to the matrix
   A(1,:)=(/ 1,  1 /)   
   A(2,:)=(/ 1, 2/)  
   B(1,:)=(/ 1, 2/)   
   C(1,:)=(/ 1,  1 /)   
   D(1,:)=(/ 1,  1 /)   
   D(2,:)=(/ 1,  3 /)  

   !E=(/A, B
   !    C, D)
   ! This shape of array
   !E=[A B
   !   C D]
   !Result should be as under
   !E=[1 1 1 2
   !   1 2 0 0
   !   1 1 1 1
   !   0 0 1 3]
  print *,E
  End program array1
```

How can I obtain this array(E) in Fortran? I am working on f90 and f95. I create a new array which is array(E). Important thing obtain E and I can improve after the array because I don't know which case or function I will use for inside an array. If it is matlab, It is easy but for fotran I don't know!

Comment: Do you want to just create a **new** array `E` from arrays `A,B,C,D` by copying the numbers or do you want them to be somehow part of `E`? Do you really require the old Fortran 90? Do you have any code you can share? How are `A,B,C,D` declared? How should `E` be declared?

Comment: f90 and f95 is possible to work on it. I create a new array and want to put inside  that array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a function, `catmat`, that gets two 2d arrays and concatenates them along a common dimension. See `E` and `F` to understand how it works. The array you want is `G`.

Notice that the allocation is done inside `catmat`.

```
program main
  implicit none
  real, dimension(2,2) :: A
  real, dimension(1,2) :: B
  real, dimension(1,2) :: C
  real, dimension(2,2) :: D
  real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: E
  real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: F
  real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: G
  integer :: i

  A = reshape( [1, 2, 3, 4], [2,2] )
  B(1,:) = [ -1, -2 ]
  C(1,:) = [ -3, -4 ]
  D = reshape( [5, 6, 7, 8], [2,2] )


  write(*,*) ( A(i,:), NEW_LINE('a'), i = 1, size(A,dim=1) )

  write(*,*) ( D(i,:), NEW_LINE('a'), i = 1, size(D,dim=1) )


  E = catmat( A, D, 1)

  write(*,*) "size of E", size(E, dim=1), size(E, dim=2)
  write(*,*) ( E(i,:), NEW_LINE('a'), i = 1, size(E,dim=1) )

  F = catmat( A, D, 2)

  write(*,*) "size of F", size(F, dim=1), size(F, dim=2)
  write(*,*) ( F(i,:), NEW_LINE('a'), i = 1, size(F,dim=1) )

  G = catmat( catmat( A, B, 1), catmat( C, D, 1), 2)

  write(*,*) "size of G", size(G, dim=1), size(G, dim=2)
  write(*,*) ( G(i,:), NEW_LINE('a'), i = 1, size(G,dim=1) )



contains
  function catmat(matl, matr, cdim) result(res)
    real, dimension(:,:), intent(in)  :: matl
    real, dimension(:,:), intent(in)  :: matr
    integer, intent(in)               :: cdim
    real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: res
    integer                           :: max_dim

    ! Assuming 2d arrays
    if( cdim .ne. 1 .and. cdim .ne. 2 ) then
      write(*,*) "ERROR"
      stop
    end if

    max_dim =  size(matl,dim=cdim)
    if ( size(matr,dim=cdim) .gt. size(matl,dim=cdim) ) max_dim = size(matr,dim=cdim)


    if( cdim .eq. 1 ) then
      allocate( res( max_dim, size(matl,dim=2) + size(matr,dim=2) ) )
    else
      allocate( res( size(matl,dim=1) + size(matr,dim=1), max_dim ) )
    end if

    res = 0

    if(cdim .eq.1 ) then
      res(:,1:size(matl,dim=2)) = matl
      res(:,size(matl,dim=2)+1:size(matl,dim=2)+size(matr,dim=2)) = matr
    else
      res(1:size(matl,dim=1),:) = matl
      res(size(matl,dim=1)+1:size(matl,dim=1)+size(matr,dim=1),:) = matr
    end if

  end function catmat

end program main
```

Comment: I tried to execute in fortran f90 but i think this is written in fortran 2003 syntax. Because i am working on f90/f95 and giving error. I dont know where i am doing wrong. Thanks for effort :)

Comment: @Nobody The `NEW_LINE` intrinsic and the `[ ]` syntax come from F2003. And also the `allocatable` result of the function is F2003 or F95 + a Technical Specification.

Comment: I have still tried to convert to code in f90. Because `function catmat(matl, matr, cdim) result(res)` is a 2003 syntax. Can someone help for f90/f95 format? I think this`(result(res))` format is not possible for f90 @Eliad and @Vladimir

Comment: @nobody The `result` clause is perfectly fine in Fortran 90. The allocatable attribute of the result variable is F2003, but the `result` keyword itself is Fortran 90. Fortran 90 is obsolete anyway, it is too old and inadequate for modern programs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all comments and helping for program  :)

Answer (score 4):

Try assigning the array, row by row, using the array concatenation operation `[a,b]`

```
Program array1
!*************************************************! 
implicit none

INTEGER, PARAMETER :: m=2 !rows
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: n=2 !cols
Real, DIMENSION(m,n) :: A,D
Real, DIMENSION(m,n) :: B,C              ! made B,C conforming

REAL, allocatable,DIMENSION(:,:) :: E

    allocate(E(2*m,2*n))
    ! Assign values to the matrix
    A(1,:)=[ 1, 1 ]   
    A(2,:)=[ 1, 2 ]  
    B(1,:)=[ 1, 2 ]   
    C(1,:)=[ 1, 1 ]   
    D(1,:)=[ 1, 1 ]   
    D(2,:)=[ 1, 3 ]

    ! This shape of array
    !E=[A B
    !   C D]

    ! assign row-by-row, using array concat
    E(1,:) = [A(1,:),B(1,:)]
    E(2,:) = [A(2,:),B(2,:)]
    E(3,:) = [C(1,:),D(1,:)]
    E(4,:) = [C(2,:),D(2,:)]

   ! print results row-by-row
    write (*,*) E(1,:)
    write (*,*) E(2,:)
    write (*,*) E(3,:)
    write (*,*) E(4,:)

End program array1
```

Alternatively, you can use array sections

```
E(1:2, 1:2) = A
E(1:1, 3:4) = B
E(3:3, 1:2) = C
E(3:4, 3:4) = D
```

Comment: There is no differrence between `(/ /)` and `[ ]`. The latter is a Fortran 2003 syntax for the same thing, the array constructor. It is not an "array concatenation operator".

Comment: @VladimirF - it is both. `c = [a, b]` concatenates `a` and `b` into `c`.

Comment: It forms an array from a and b, whatever they are. But the combination of `(/ /)` in the first half of the code and then suddenly `[ ]` in the other half of the code, combined with the inexact name (or a name not found in the standard) and the fact that the OP requested F95, warranted a clarification comment IMO.

Comment: @VladimirF - I edited the post to remove the "old" `(\ X \)` notation with the "new" `[ X ]`.